# A simple image above everything (includes posts)

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am quite new at coding, and I would love spend a lot of time with it, but now I really do not have time for that. I spent two weeks to trying to find out this thing.

I made my portoflio on tumblr. And I used a theme, where the pictures are filling the whole screen, so you can not basically anything, but pictures. Which is good, I wanted it like this. BUT. I would like to leave a little note, actually a [pointing arrow picture](https://s17.postimg.org/5b1we32j3/point.png) which says: "keep scrolling for more". So this note is always hidden by the full-sized images.

How can I move the note-image on the very top? Above the image posts?
Which is the easiest way?

I tried some resolution, i have found here, but none of them worked...
I thought would not be a problem, but this is my portfolio, and I still could not send it, because of this issue. 
Thank you so much for any help. Sorry for being so dumb. 
This is my [portfolio](http://www.fruzsina-majer.tumblr.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just adding the property z-index: xx to the image (or actually whatever) you want to be above anything else. Also, you can combine it with position absolute or fixed.

`div { width: 100px; height: 100px;  }
    .container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
    }
    .green {
      position: relative;
      left: 20px;
      top: 20px;
      background-color: green;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .pink {
      position: relative;
      left: 80px;
      top: 0px;
      background-color: pink;
      z-index: 3;
    }
http://codepen.io/paulirish/pen/CgAo`

here you can see various examples, credit for Tom Wiltzius

Comment: Thank you for helping, but It still seems does not work in my case. :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with tumblr, but based on your tags it looks like it uses HTML and CSS. When you have an image that fills the entire screen and want to add an image on top of that image, you need to have both images within a div `container` to give them something to reference. This `container` needs to have `position: relative` and the style of the images will be relative to it. So, your HTML and CSS should look something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="imageOne" src="path/url goes here" alt="" />
    <img class="imageTwo" src="path/url goes here" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.imageOne {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}    
.imageTwo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}
```

So your first image is set to `0 pixels` from the top and `0 pixels` from the left. This mates it to the `container` div you created to hold the images and set it to the same positioning. Your second image is `position: absolute` to the `container` div so it is `30 pixels` from the top and `30 pixels` from the left and was loaded after your first image and thus placed on top!

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help, I have tried this version, but I failed at some points.
First was, the thing I want to be hidden by the pic is not a simple image. That is a flowing dash of image-posts, an always changing picture-flow, what you can scroll over, so I do not know, how can I use this form in my case with posts. I tried like this, and you can see the result on my page above. <div class="container">
    <div class="posts" src="" alt="" />
    <img class="imageTwo" src="https://s17.postimg.org/5b1we32j3/point.png" alt="" />
</div>

Comment: I cant actually view tumblr (we keep it blocked on my computer for the kids). So it sounds like what you want to do is put one image atop a `div` that happens to be a flowing series of images. If that's the case, you can get rid of the imageTwo class above and apply the styles to just container and imageOne. The flowing images would belong to the container `div` and you would use imageOne to put on top.

Ill need an image and your source code otherwise to give you a better answer.